# Mysql syntax to update a column field using user id

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, node.js, syntax

I need to develop an e-commerce website using node js and MySQL for my college course.
In the checkout process, I am asked to allow the user to enter a delivery address and update the user table's correspondent field.
The following code works when I set a specific id (ex id=100) in the query, but what if I don't want to specify a value?

I've tried something like id=? (see my code) but I'm getting an error syntax.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Mara

```js
app.post('/submitaddress', function (req, res) {
    
    // catching the variables
    var address = req.body.address;
    
    // put the data in the database
    // pulling in mysql
    var mysql = require('mysql');

  
    // set up a connection  
    var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    database: "test",
    password: ""
    });
    
      con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected!");
  var sql = "UPDATE `test`.`users` SET `address`='"+address+"' WHERE  id=100;";
  console.log(sql);
  con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("1 record inserted");
  });
});
        
    res.send('address added');
  
})
```

```html
<!--CHECKOUT PAGE-->
<div data-role="page" id="checkout">

    <div data-role="header">
        <div class="flex-container">
            <img class="responsive-2" src="images/logo_yes.png">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
         
        <h1>Delivery address</h1>
        
        Delivery address <input type="text" id="address"/> <br>
        <button id="submitorder">Submit order</button>
    
    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer">        
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#homepage" data-icon="home"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-icon="shop"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-icon="phone"></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    
</div><!-- /page -->
```

```js
app.post('/submitaddress', function (req, res) {
    
    // catching the variables
    var address = req.body.address;
    
    // put the data in the database
    // pulling in mysql
    var mysql = require('mysql');

  
    // set up a connection  
    var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    database: "test",
    password: ""
    });
    
      con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected!");
  var sql = "UPDATE `test`.`users` SET `address`='"+address+"' WHERE  `id`=?;";
  console.log(sql);
  con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("1 record inserted");
  });
});
        
    res.send('address added');
  
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Run the following code using node then you will understand where to place you authentication code and use the result User ID in the API you want to update the address.

By using a middleware you can add a common authentication method for all your routes and the result can be passed on to the API method using res.locals object, This is quite useful in many scenarios.

```js
var express = require('express');
const http = require("http");
const debug = require("debug")("node-angular");

let app = express();

console.log("Server Started");

const auth = (req, res, next) => {
    // Process the authorization header of the Request here and determine the logged in user
    res.locals.userID = 100;
    next();
};


app.get('/get', auth, async (req, res) => {
    try {
        res.status(201).json({
            details: "Secret User ID: "+res.locals.userID
        });

    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).json({
            details: "Internal Error!"
        });
    }
});


// Server Start


const normalizePort = val => {
    var port = parseInt(val, 10);

    if (isNaN(port)) {
        // named pipe
        return val;
    }

    if (port >= 0) {
        // port number
        return port;
    }

    return false;
};

const onError = error => {
    if (error.syscall !== "listen") {
        throw error;
    }
    const bind = typeof addr === "string" ? "pipe " + addr : "port " + port;
    switch (error.code) {
        case "EACCES":
            console.error(bind + " requires elevated privileges");
            process.exit(1);
            break;
        case "EADDRINUSE":
            console.error(bind + " is already in use");
            process.exit(1);
            break;
        default:
            throw error;
    }
};

const onListening = () => {
    const addr = server.address();
    const bind = typeof addr === "string" ? "pipe " + addr : "port " + port;
    debug("Listening on " + bind);
};

const port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || "3000");
app.set("port", port);

const server = http.createServer(app);
server.on("error", onError);
server.on("listening", onListening);
server.listen(port);
```

Comment: Thanks SaiSurya for you help. Unfortunately, it's not what I'm looking for. If I pass the argument "100" for the id the system updates the address of user 100 no matter what user is logged in. I'd like my program to recognise the user that is logged in and updates the correct address field.

Comment: Ohh then you should use a middleware to process current user details and by that you can update the record of the logged in user. Can you please tell me what kind of authentication you use in this application like JWT.

Comment: Please checkout the update. If you want to use JWT or JSON web token authentication in your application then you can refer my public MEAN login repo to do that. Thank You, 
Link: https://github.com/SaiSurya9999/MEAN-Login-System

Comment: Your solution is much more advanced than my level but thanks a million for taking the time to reply.